# Laravel: User gets logged out before session expires

Tags: laravel, session, csrf

I am working on a web app made in Laravel and encountered a weird issue.
The SESSION_LIFETIME is set to 30 minutes so I have a script on the front-end that checks user's remaining time in session 3 minutes before the 30 minutes are up. This is done by setting a session_expires_at variable on the backend every time the user takes an action.
Expiry time is calculated like this **Now + SESSION_LIFETIME**

The main issue is that the user somehow gets logged out before the 30 minutes are up. If I set the lifetime to 20 minutes, there is no problem.

I tested this by adding some logs

```
[2021-10-22 17:32:01] testing.INFO: Reached CheckOktaTokenForWeb
[2021-10-22 17:32:01] testing.INFO: 2021-10-22 17:32
[2021-10-22 17:32:01] testing.INFO: Session expires at: 2021-10-22 18:02
[2021-10-22 17:32:01] testing.INFO: Okta token is valid
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: Reached VerifyCsrfToken
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: 2021-10-22 17:59
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: Session Lifetime: 30
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: User is authenticated? No
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: Reached VerifyCsrfToken
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: 2021-10-22 17:59
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: Session Lifetime: 30
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: User is authenticated? No
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: Reached VerifyCsrfToken
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: 2021-10-22 17:59
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: Session Lifetime: 30
[2021-10-22 17:59:01] testing.INFO: User is authenticated? No
```

From the logs you can see that 3 minutes before the session lifetime ends, the user is not authenticated. The user does nothing in between these two time periods so something logs him out, but I am all out of ideas what.

CheckOktaTokenForWeb is a custom middleware that gets called after Laravel's Auth middleware which just checks the third-party auth token, that's also where I set the session_expires_at attribute.

What else could be logging the user out before the 30 minutes have passed and gives me a token mismatch error? As I said, if I set session lifetime to 20 minutes, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

And the culprit was the `session.gc_maxlifetime` setting in php.ini being set to 24 minutes.